# Adding 3 way switches

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I have a switch that controls the top and bottom of an outlet.  I would like to make the outlet hot all the time.  Additionally I would like to install a light fixture, convert the existing single switch to a 3 way and install a new 3 way switch on a different wall.  @tester101 explained to me how to do something similar yesterday, but without the 3 way switches.  What is the best/easiest way to accomplish this?
EDIT 
Switch
[image: switch]
Back of the switch
[image: back of outlet]
Outlet[image: outlet]
Back of outlet
[image: back of switch]

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the switch boxes and the receptacle box please?

Comment: We still need a photo looking into the back of the first switch box -- also, I take it the second and third photos are of the same thing, right?

Comment: Sorry, I have labeled the pictures now.  The switch box pictured is the only one I have currently.  I would like to rewire it so the outlet is always hot, also change it out to be a 3 way.  And then add a second 3 way switch.

Comment: @tester101 any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. It's a showing a three way connection with power coming from one switch.

[image]

Comment: how does the outlet complicate this?  If I just connect the existing wires (2 black 1 red) and run a pigtail to the common on SW1, this will keep the outlet hot all the time right?  Then I run 3 wire from SW1 to SW2, connecting black and red wires as shown.  What about white? I see it is wire nutted to the white from the power source in the diagram.  The switch currently has 2 whites already wire nutted together in the box, so do I just add the new white to these?

Comment: If you look on the drawing where it shows the source first switch, it shows the black wire connection to the switch. This would be the wire to attach to to continue to your receptacle. The wire which is colored grey is your neutral which should continue all the way to your fixture and also you tap to go to your receptacle along with your ground. Hope this helps.